# Register new user as authenitcated user in drupal using xml-rpc

Tags: php, drupal, xml-rpc, drupal-services

I'm trying to write PHP script for adding new users in drupal 7 using services module.

So far I managed to create one, but as a anonymous user. When I run the script with administrator only permissions, I get Notice:

> Access denied for user anonymous (403), although I send the username and password in the request.

Any ideas what should I try to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the User Register service resource when logged in as any type of authenticated user. This is very similar to Drupal's default behavior in that when you're logged in, you can't fill out the registration form. Instead you need to call the User Create service resource.

Do a **POST** to `?q=[my-endpoint]/user.json` and send along data similar to the following:

`{
  account: {
    name: 'bob',
    mail: 'bob@hotmail.com',
  }
}`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried with user.create but I still get the same error. First I login the user with user.login than I get the X-CSRF-TOKEN and SESSION and set these header parameters in user.create call...but it's not working. Do you have some idea? Thank you!

Comment: The logged in user will need the `administer users` permission to be able to create a user (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/resources/user_resource.inc?h=7.x-3.x#n806). If that still doesn't work, review the Drupal watchdog logs to see if it has any hint as to why it is failing.